# R: Within List of Lists, Reverse Each List Order

Tags: r, list, if-statement

I have a list of lists.  I want to reverse the order of the elements within each list.  I am using this within a for loop, but I've provided a simplified example below.

```
r1 = c(1,2,3)
r2 = c(4,5,6)
r3 = c(7,8,9)

all <- list(Rep1 = as.list(r1),
            Rep2 = as.list(r2),
            Rep3 = as.list(r3))
```

`rev(all)` reverses the order of the individual lists but retains the order the list elements.

I've also tried to apply `rev()` during list assembly, but for my purposes this requires an `ifelse` statement.  For some reason this results in only returning the first element of each list.

```
Strand = "+"

allrev <- list(
  Rep1 = ifelse(Strand == "+", as.list(r1), rev(as.list(r1))),
  Rep2 = ifelse(Strand == "+", as.list(r2), rev(as.list(r2))),
  Rep3 = ifelse(Strand == "+", as.list(r3), rev(as.list(r3)))
)
```

```
> allrev
$Rep1
$Rep1[[1]]
[1] 1


$Rep2
$Rep2[[1]]
[1] 4


$Rep3
$Rep3[[1]]
[1] 7
```

Desired Output

```
all_rev <- list(
  Rep1 = as.list(c(3,2,1)),
  Rep2 = as.list(c(6,5,4)),
  Rep3 = as.list(c(9,8,7))
  )
```

**Solution (Method Suggested by Gregor)**

```
Strand = "-"
all_rev <- list(
  Rep1 = if(Strand == "+") as.list(r1) else rev(as.list(r1)),
  Rep2 = if(Strand == "+") as.list(r2) else rev(as.list(r2)),
  Rep3 = if(Strand == "+") as.list(r3) else rev(as.list(r3))
  )

> all_rev
$Rep1
$Rep1[[1]]
[1] 3

$Rep1[[2]]
[1] 2

$Rep1[[3]]
[1] 1


$Rep2
$Rep2[[1]]
[1] 6

$Rep2[[2]]
[1] 5

$Rep2[[3]]
[1] 4


$Rep3
$Rep3[[1]]
[1] 9

$Rep3[[2]]
[1] 8

$Rep3[[3]]
[1] 7
```

Comment: `ifelse` "returns an object of the same shape as the `test` argument". `Strand == "+"` has length 1, so `ifelse(Strand == "+", ...)` must have length 1 result. Use `if(){}else{}` for running general purpose code.

Comment: Are you looking for `lapply(all, rev)`? If you would show your desired output, it will make it easier to help.

Comment: Updated post to include the desired output.  Used your suggestion with if() else(), but couldn't accept it as an answer? If you have a nicer way using lapply please share so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply the function `rev` to each list item:

```
solution <- lapply(all, rev)
identical(solution, all_rev)
# [1] TRUE
```

You can, of course, make this conditional using `if()`:

```
if(Strand == "+") {
  all <- lapply(all, rev)
}
```

If you don't like `lapply`, you can also use a `for` loop:

```
if(Strand == "+") {
  for(i in seq_along(all)) {
    all[[i]] <- rev(all[[i]])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Gregor.  I am terrible with the various apply functions.  It seems they are almost always the answer when I get stuck lol.